# How to parse this nested json string in javascript

Tags: javascript

```
{"usercredentials": { "user": {"id": 194}, "modules": {"module": { "roles": {"role": {"name": "Channel Partner Sales User","id": 5 "previllage": {"name": "Product Sales User","id": 6},"URl": "asdfdsf"}},"name": "Channel Partners","id": 4,"URl": "adfsfddf" }} }}
```

Answer (score 0):

There's an error in your JSON. You cannot parse it:

```
{
    "usercredentials": {
        "user": {},
        "modules": {
            "module": {
                "roles": {
                    "role": {
                        "name": "Channel Partner Sales User",
                        "id": 5,
                        "previllage": {},
                        "URl": "192.168.1.11:8080/SSS/chp/dashboard.html";
//-------------- You cannot have stuff like this-------------------------^
                    }
                },
                "name": "Channel Partners",
                "id": 4,
                "URl": "192.168.1.11:8080/SSS/chp/dashboard.html";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: actually it there but when i was posting it went wrong i guess

Comment: i am posting the correct formate please check out onces

Comment: {  
   "usercredentials":{  
      "user":{  },
      "modules":{  
         "module":{  
            "roles":{  
               "role":{  
                  "name":"Channel Partner Sales User",
                  "id":5,
                  "previllage":{  },
                  "URl":"http://192.168.1.11:8080/SSS/chp/dashboard.html"
               }
            },
            "name":"Channel Partners",
            "id":4,
            "URl":"http://192.168.1.11:8080/SSS/chp/dashboard.html"
         }
      }
   }
}

Comment: this is my json string it should be called recursively to get all the values of its child

Comment: @MaryalaBharath Even now it is wrong.

Comment: {"usercredentials": {
    "user": {"id": 195},
    "modules": {"module": {
        "roles": {"role": {
            "name": "Sales Person",
            "id": 6,
            "previllage": {
                "name": "Channel Partner Sales User",
                "id": 7
            },
            "URl": "http://192.168.1.11:8080/SSS/sales/dashboard.html"
        }},
        "name": "Distributers",
        "id": 5,
        "URl": "http://192.168.1.11:8080/SSS/sales/dashboard.html"
    }}
}}

Comment: please check this one onces

Comment: @MaryalaBharath **Wrong**!

Comment: can u please show me where exactly the error is

Comment: @MaryalaBharath Check with [JSON Lint](http://jsonlint.com/).

Comment: it has given the output valid json object

Comment: @MaryalaBharath Which one?

Comment: {"usercredentials": {
    "user": {"id": 195},
    "modules": {"module": {
        "roles": {"role": {
            "name": "Sales Person",
            "id": 6,
            "previllage": {
                "name": "Channel Partner Sales User",
                "id": 7
            },
            "URl": "http://192.168.1.11:8080/SSS/sales/dashboard.html"
        }},
        "name": "Distributers",
        "id": 5,
        "URl": "http://192.168.1.11:8080/SSS/sales/dashboard.html"
    }}
}}

Comment: @MaryalaBharath Where does it say as valid JSON?

Comment: i have checked with JSON Lint

Comment: In JSON `;` is invalid. Can you kindly get me a screenshot, as I guess, it is displaying differently here.

Comment: k how can i make that as an valid one please hell me i am badly structed i have coneverted xml to json to get this structure

Comment: @MaryalaBharath Will you listen? Remove the `;` from there.